# Userscript sometimes gives 405

Tags: javascript, button, tampermonkey, userscripts, http-status-code-405

I am trying to create a (Tampermonkey) userscript to automate the process of accepting an agreement for when I need to access a certain network (as it becomes annoying to accept the agreement each and every time I do connect to that network).

The webpage is accessed from [detectportal.firefox.com](https://detectportal.firefox.com), or the button on Firefox (the browser I am currently using). From the webpage, there are two buttons where one is to accept the agreement while the other is to reject. With the current code I have, it tests to see if the button exists, then automates the click for the accept button through `setTimeout()`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto Login
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Simple auto-login Tampermonkey script
// @author       Bill Joe
// @match        example.com/*
// @icon         example_image
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  "use strict";
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]) { // <-- accept button selector
        setTimeout(document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click(), 8000); // 8 second wait
    }
})();
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes the page throws a 405 error when the script is ran.

Is there any way this can be fixed? (Ideally, I would not like to use `setTimeout()`)

Answer (score 0):

[405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) is a response header. It might be related to the data that is being sent e.g. data is incomplete. Without having a test site, it is difficult to guess what is happening.

Here are a few general comments that might be useful.

- Running the userscript after the page is fully loaded i.e. `@run-at  document-idle` would often result in all element being present, unless the element is created later via JavaScript
- `document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]` means:

  - Traverse the entire DOM and make a list of all the elements found
  - Only use the first one and leave all others
  - `querySelector()` will look for the first one and then stops looking any further, thus more efficient
- It is recommended to search for the same item only once e.g.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');
if (btn) {
  // do something
}
```

Here is the same userscript that you can work on. It uses [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) but you can also use the above code snippet.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto Login
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Simple auto-login Tampermonkey script
// @author       Bill Joe
// @match        example.com/*
// @icon         example_image
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  "use strict";
  // Optional Chaining, if found then click
  document.querySelector('.button')?.click();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @erosman I will try the code snippet out once I connect to the network again! :)

Comment: I am still receiving a 405. The script does indeed run; however, upon authentication, it persists with the 405 error.

Comment: @BillJoe There could be other factors involved like the JavaScript on that page. It is diffcult to guess without somewhere to test it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/testwebsite-j3syfc Thanks for helping :)

I will not test the network until next week as I am away from it (EST time).

Comment: @BillJoe The page has errors e.g. on clicking the button `submitAction is not defined`

Comment: I fixed most of the errors (such as the picture and text content display), though it seems like the issue is that the function deals with the browser URL, which is not something I can integrate into the test website due to various reasons (eg. the website not allowing it). Other information that may be useful is that the start URL being https://detectportal.firefox.com

Comment: @BillJoe The target URL can also be the issue as some sites have specific restrictions in browsers.

Comment: I will check to see if the JS is browser-specific next time I am able to connect to the network.

Comment: Seems to have the same code for most of the browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc).

Comment: Shall this be taken to a discussion?